# Amazon LightSail + External Database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-lightsail, lucee, lightsail-container-service

I have a Lucee installation using Docker on an Amazon Lightsail container but I want to connect to an external MSSQL database on a different server. If I run the docker on my local machine I can connect to the database no problem - i've set up a login to the database server to a specific database and that is included in the lucee website configuration.

The problem is that when the Lucee installation is run on Lightsail it doesnt connect to the external database, it just times out and says:

"The TCP/IP connection to the host , port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

I added the 1433 port to the deployment settings in but is there anything else needing to be set up on LightSail?